# Inserting an image in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Im trying to insert an image my documentation page,going through the documentation i have it done like this

```
**Tutorial on Training model**
==============================


.. image::/home/predible/Desktop/sixfortyintofoureighty.png
```

When i run

`make html`

It does not throw any error but the image does not display in the documentation,Any suggestions on how do i get my image to display would be really helpful,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There should be a space between `.. image::` and the path to the image.
2. The image path must either be relative to the source file, or absolute which means that it is relative to the top source directory (see http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images).

Comment: Thanks for your time