# Readthedoc and sphinx image path

Tags: restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I'm trying to build the doc for a Python package on readthedoc.org using sphinx on rst files. The doc is built as expected except for images that I'm unable to properly reference. What would be the proper way to reference the image produced by mycommand ? My solution doesn't work...

```
.. command-output:: mycommand >  example_01.png
    :shell:

.. image:: ./example_01.png
    :target: ./example_01.png
    :width: 75%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting an image in sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435026/inserting-an-image-in-sphinx)

Comment: The problem is that the solution above works on my laptop but not on readthedoc server. I guess there is something I missed about the way images files are organized/copied on readthedoc server... Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: Check the log files in RTD builds to find what happened. Report back.